# How can I save my current imageview when onClick?

Tags: android, image, save

How can I save my current ImageView when I press onClick?
Im currently having the problem that the image that is next in line is being saved instead of the current actual image..

**My Code for saving onLike**

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SwipeView.OnCardSwipedListener {

        // Declaring variables
        private final static int CARDS_MAX_ELEMENTS = 5;
        private FrameLayout contentLayout;
        private SwipeView mSwipeView;
        private View addCardc41;
        private Firebase mRef;
        public ImageView imageLogo;
        public ImageView imageview;
        private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";

        // Creating array of meals, getting them from the drawable folder
        private int[] meals = {
                R.drawable.a,
                R.drawable.b,
                R.drawable.c,
                R.drawable.d,
                R.drawable.e,
                R.drawable.f,
                R.drawable.g,
                R.drawable.h,
                R.drawable.i,
                R.drawable.j
        };

        // Declaring a counter for the next method
          private int count = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_swipe_view_demo);
        contentLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.contentLayout);
        imageLogo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        // Add the swipe view
        mSwipeView = new SwipeView(this, R.id.imgSwipeLike, R.id.imgSwipeNope,
                this);
        contentLayout.addView(mSwipeView);


        // Adding the cards initially with the maximum limits of cards.
        for (int i = 0; i < CARDS_MAX_ELEMENTS; i++) {
            addCard(i);
        }

    }

    /**
     * On clicked view.
     *
     * @param clickedView
     *            the clicked view
     */
    public void onClickedView(View clickedView) {
        switch (clickedView.getId()) {
            case R.id.imgDisLike: {
                mSwipeView.dislikeCard();
                break;
            }

            case R.id.imgLike: {
                mSwipeView.likeCard();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLikes() {
        imageview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true); //Add this line.
        imageview.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap bm=imageview.getDrawingCache();

        OutputStream fOut = null;
        Uri outputFileUri;
        try {
            File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + File.separator + "folder_name" + File.separator);
            root.mkdirs();
            File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(root, "myPicName.jpg");
            outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);
            fOut = new FileOutputStream(sdImageMainDirectory);
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[] { sdImageMainDirectory.getAbsolutePath() }, null, null);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error occured. Please try again later.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        try {
            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
            fOut.flush();
            fOut.close();
        } catch (Exception e){}
        System.out.println("An Card removed");
        // Add a card if you needed after any previous card swiped
        addCard(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisLikes() {
        System.out.println("An Card removed");
        // Add a card if you needed after any previous card swiped
        addCard(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSingleTap() {

    }
    /**
     * Adds the card to the swipe.
     */

    private void addCard(int position) {
        final View cardView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(
                R.layout.item_swipe_view, null);
        final ImageView imgMeal = (ImageView) cardView
                .findViewById(R.id.imgMeals);
        imgMeal.setImageResource(meals[count]);
        count++;
        if (count == meals.length) {
            count = 0;
        }
        // Add a card to the swipe view..
        mSwipeView.addCard(cardView, position);

        // Create OnClickListener for the CookBookActivity
        // Declare Button for the Cookbook
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, CookbookActivity.class));
            }
        });

        // Check Authentication
        mRef = new Firebase(Constants.FIREBASE_URL);
        if (mRef.getAuth() == null) {
            loadLoginView();
        }
    }

    private void loadLoginView() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


}
```

**The Library that i'm using for the swiping**

```
//
// credits to IntelliJ IDEA
// (powered by Fernflower decompiler)

   package com.rk.lib.view;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.os.Build.VERSION;
    import android.view.GestureDetector;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
    import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
    import android.view.animation.AlphaAnimation;
    import android.widget.FrameLayout;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams;

    public class SwipeView extends FrameLayout {
        private View mFocusedView;
        private View mFocusedViewLike;
        private View mFocusedViewNope;
        private int mFocusedViewWidth;
        private float mPreviousAlpha = 0.0F;
        private Integer mLikeResource = Integer.valueOf(0);
        private Integer mNopeResource = Integer.valueOf(0);
        private static final int MAX_ELEMENTS = 3;
        private static final long DELAY_SCROLL_RUNNABLE = 1L;
        private static final int SCROLL_LENGTH = 5;
        private int mScrolledPixelsX;
        private int mScrolledPixelsY;
        private int mNeedToScrollX;
        private int mNeedToScrollY;
        private int mTotalScrolledX;
        private int mTotalScrolledY;
        private int mScrollLengthX = 5;
        private int mScrollLengthY = 5;
        private boolean enableTouchSwipe = true;
        private Context mContext;
        private SwipeView.ScrollMode mScrollModeX;
        private SwipeView.ScrollMode mScrollModeY;
        private SwipeView.ScrollDirection mScrollDirection;
        private int[] paddingX;
        private int[] paddingYTop;
        private int[] paddingYBottom;
        private SwipeView.OnCardSwipedListener mOnCardSwipedListener;
        private Handler mScrollHandler;
        private Runnable mScrollRunnable;
        private final SimpleOnGestureListener simpleOnGestureListener;

        public SwipeView(Context context, Integer likeResource, Integer nopeResource, SwipeView.OnCardSwipedListener cardSwipeListener) {
            super(context);
            this.mScrollModeX = SwipeView.ScrollMode.NONE;
            this.mScrollModeY = SwipeView.ScrollMode.NONE;
            this.mScrollDirection = SwipeView.ScrollDirection.NONE;
            this.paddingX = new int[]{0, 10, 20};
            this.paddingYTop = new int[]{0, 10, 20};
            this.paddingYBottom = new int[]{20, 10, 0};
            this.mScrollHandler = new Handler();
            this.mScrollRunnable = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    boolean scrollX;
                    boolean scrollY;
                    int scrollX1;
                    int scrollY1;
                    if(SwipeView.this.mScrollDirection == SwipeView.ScrollDirection.OUT) {
                        if(SwipeView.this.mNeedToScrollX <= 0 && SwipeView.this.mNeedToScrollY <= 0) {
                            SwipeView.this.mScrollHandler.removeCallbacks(SwipeView.this.mScrollRunnable);
                            SwipeView.this.removeView(SwipeView.this.mFocusedView);
                            if(SwipeView.this.mScrollModeX == SwipeView.ScrollMode.LEFT) {
                                SwipeView.this.mOnCardSwipedListener.onLikes();
                            } else if(SwipeView.this.mScrollModeX == SwipeView.ScrollMode.RIGHT) {
                                SwipeView.this.mOnCardSwipedListener.onDisLikes();
                            }

                            SwipeView.this.alignCardsPadding();
                        } else {
                            if(SwipeView.this.mNeedToScrollX < SwipeView.this.mScrollLengthX) {
                                SwipeView.this.mScrollLengthX = SwipeView.this.mNeedToScrollX;
                                SwipeView.this.mNeedToScrollX = 0;
                            } else {
                                SwipeView.this.mNeedToScrollX = SwipeView.this.mNeedToScrollX - SwipeView.this.mScrollLengthX;
                            }

                            if(SwipeView.this.mNeedToScrollY < SwipeView.this.mScrollLengthY) {
                                SwipeView.this.mScrollLengthY = SwipeView.this.mNeedToScrollY;
                                SwipeView.this.mNeedToScrollY = 0;
                            } else {
                                SwipeView.this.mNeedToScrollY = SwipeView.this.mNeedToScrollY - SwipeView.this.mScrollLengthY;
                            }

                            scrollX = false;
                            scrollY = false;
                            if(SwipeView.this.mScrollModeX == SwipeView.ScrollMode.LEFT) {
                                scrollX1 = -SwipeView.this.mScrollLengthX;
                            } else {
                                scrollX1 = SwipeView.this.mScrollLengthX;
                            }

                            if(SwipeView.this.mScrollModeY == SwipeView.ScrollMode.TOP) {
                                scrollY1 = -SwipeView.this.mScrollLengthY;
                            } else {
                                scrollY1 = SwipeView.this.mScrollLengthY;
                            }

                            SwipeView.this.mFocusedView.scrollBy(scrollX1, scrollY1);
                            SwipeView.this.mScrollHandler.postDelayed(SwipeView.this.mScrollRunnable, 1L);
                        }
                    } else if(SwipeView.this.mScrollDirection == SwipeView.ScrollDirection.IN) {
                        if(SwipeView.this.mTotalScrolledX <= 0 && SwipeView.this.mTotalScrolledY <= 0) {
                            SwipeView.this.mScrollHandler.removeCallbacks(SwipeView.this.mScrollRunnable);
                            SwipeView.this.mScrollDirection = SwipeView.ScrollDirection.NONE;
                        } else {
                            if(SwipeView.this.mTotalScrolledX < SwipeView.this.mScrollLengthX) {
                                SwipeView.this.mScrollLengthX = SwipeView.this.mTotalScrolledX;
                                SwipeView.this.mTotalScrolledX = 0;
                            } else {
                                SwipeView.this.mTotalScrolledX = SwipeView.this.mTotalScrolledX - SwipeView.this.mScrollLengthX;
                            }

                            if(SwipeView.this.mTotalScrolledY < SwipeView.this.mScrollLengthY) {
                                SwipeView.this.mScrollLengthY = SwipeView.this.mTotalScrolledY;
                                SwipeView.this.mTotalScrolledY = 0;
                            } else {
                                SwipeView.this.mTotalScrolledY = SwipeView.this.mTotalScrolledY - SwipeView.this.mScrollLengthY;
                            }

                            scrollX = false;
                            scrollY = false;
                            if(SwipeView.this.mScrollModeX == SwipeView.ScrollMode.LEFT) {
                                scrollX1 = SwipeView.this.mScrollLengthX;
                            } else {
                                scrollX1 = -SwipeView.this.mScrollLengthX;
                            }

                            if(SwipeView.this.mScrollModeY == SwipeView.ScrollMode.TOP) {
                                scrollY1 = -SwipeView.this.mScrollLengthY;
                            } else {
                                scrollY1 = SwipeView.this.mScrollLengthY;
                            }

                            SwipeView.this.mFocusedView.scrollBy(scrollX1, scrollY1);
                            SwipeView.this.mScrollHandler.postDelayed(SwipeView.this.mScrollRunnable, 1L);
                        }
                    }

                }
            };
            this.simpleOnGestureListener = new SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
                    SwipeView.this.mOnCardSwipedListener.onSingleTap();
                    return super.onSingleTapConfirmed(e);
                }

                public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
                    if(SwipeView.this.mFocusedView != null) {
                        SwipeView.this.mScrolledPixelsX = SwipeView.this.mScrolledPixelsX + (int)distanceX;
                        SwipeView.this.mScrolledPixelsY = SwipeView.this.mScrolledPixelsY + (int)distanceY;
                        SwipeView.this.mFocusedView.scrollBy((int)distanceX, (int)distanceY);
                        float alpha = (float)SwipeView.this.mScrolledPixelsX / (float)SwipeView.this.mFocusedViewWidth;
                        if(alpha > 0.0F) {
                            SwipeView.this.mFocusedViewNope.setVisibility(0);
                            SwipeView.this.mFocusedViewLike.setVisibility(8);
                            SwipeView.setAlpha(SwipeView.this.mFocusedViewNope, SwipeView.this.mPreviousAlpha, alpha);
                            SwipeView.this.mPreviousAlpha = alpha;
                        } else {
                            SwipeView.this.mFocusedViewNope.setVisibility(8);
                            SwipeView.this.mFocusedViewLike.setVisibility(0);
                            SwipeView.setAlpha(SwipeView.this.mFocusedViewLike, SwipeView.this.mPreviousAlpha, -alpha);
                            SwipeView.this.mPreviousAlpha = -alpha;
                        }
                    }

                    return true;
                }
            };
            this.mContext = context;
            this.mLikeResource = likeResource;
            this.mNopeResource = nopeResource;
            this.mOnCardSwipedListener = cardSwipeListener;
            float density = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

            for(int gestureDetector = 0; gestureDetector < this.paddingX.length; ++gestureDetector) {
                this.paddingX[gestureDetector] = (int)((float)this.paddingX[gestureDetector] * density);
                this.paddingYTop[gestureDetector] = (int)((float)this.paddingYTop[gestureDetector] * density);
                this.paddingYBottom[gestureDetector] = (int)((float)this.paddingYBottom[gestureDetector] * density);
            }

            final GestureDetector var7 = new GestureDetector(this.mContext, this.simpleOnGestureListener);
            this.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    if(SwipeView.this.getChildCount() > 0) {
                        if(SwipeView.this.mScrollDirection != SwipeView.ScrollDirection.NONE) {
                            return false;
                        } else if(!SwipeView.this.enableTouchSwipe) {
                            return false;
                        } else {
                            var7.onTouchEvent(event);
                            switch(event.getAction()) {
                            case 0:
                                if(SwipeView.this.getChildCount() > 0) {
                                    SwipeView.this.mFocusedView = SwipeView.this.getChildAt(SwipeView.this.getChildCount() - 1);
                                    SwipeView.this.mFocusedViewLike = SwipeView.this.mFocusedView.findViewById(SwipeView.this.mLikeResource.intValue());
                                    SwipeView.this.mFocusedViewNope = SwipeView.this.mFocusedView.findViewById(SwipeView.this.mNopeResource.intValue());
                                    SwipeView.this.mFocusedViewWidth = SwipeView.this.mFocusedView.getWidth();
                                    SwipeView.this.mFocusedView.setPadding(SwipeView.this.paddingX[0], 0, SwipeView.this.paddingX[0], 0);
                                }

                                SwipeView.this.resetScrollingValues();
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                SwipeView.this.alignCardsPadding();
                                if(SwipeView.this.mScrolledPixelsX < 0) {
                                    SwipeView.this.mScrollModeX = SwipeView.ScrollMode.LEFT;
                                    SwipeView.this.mTotalScrolledX = -SwipeView.this.mScrolledPixelsX;
                                } else {
                                    SwipeView.this.mScrollModeX = SwipeView.ScrollMode.RIGHT;
                                    SwipeView.this.mTotalScrolledX = SwipeView.this.mScrolledPixelsX;
                                }

                                if(SwipeView.this.mScrolledPixelsY < 0) {
                                    SwipeView.this.mScrollModeY = SwipeView.ScrollMode.BOTTOM;
                                    SwipeView.this.mTotalScrolledY = -SwipeView.this.mScrolledPixelsY;
                                } else {
                                    SwipeView.this.mScrollModeY = SwipeView.ScrollMode.TOP;
                                    SwipeView.this.mTotalScrolledY = SwipeView.this.mScrolledPixelsY;
                                }

                                SwipeView.this.detectSwipe();
                            }

                            return true;
                        }
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        public void addCard(View view, int position) {
            if(this.getChildCount() <= 3 && position < 3) {
                LinearLayout viewLayout = new LinearLayout(this.mContext);
                viewLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(-1, -1));
                view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(-1, -1));
                viewLayout.addView(view);
                viewLayout.setPadding(this.paddingX[position], this.paddingYTop[position], this.paddingX[position], this.paddingYBottom[position]);
                this.addView(viewLayout, 0);
            }

        }

        public void removeFocusedCard() {
            this.removeView(this.mFocusedView);
            this.alignCardsPadding();
        }

        private void alignCardsPadding() {
            int i = 0;

            for(int j = this.getChildCount() - 1; j >= 0; --j) {
                this.getChildAt(j).setPadding(this.paddingX[i], this.paddingYTop[i], this.paddingX[i], this.paddingYBottom[i]);
                ++i;
            }

            this.mScrollDirection = SwipeView.ScrollDirection.NONE;
        }

        private void resetScrollingValues() {
            this.mPreviousAlpha = 0.0F;
            this.mNeedToScrollX = 0;
            this.mScrolledPixelsX = 0;
            this.mTotalScrolledX = 0;
            this.mNeedToScrollY = 0;
            this.mScrolledPixelsY = 0;
            this.mTotalScrolledY = 0;
            this.mScrollLengthX = 5;
            this.mScrollLengthY = 5;
            this.mScrollModeX = SwipeView.ScrollMode.NONE;
            this.mScrollModeY = SwipeView.ScrollMode.NONE;
        }

        public void resetFocuedView() {
            if(this.getChildCount() > 0) {
                View mFocusedView = this.getChildAt(this.getChildCount() - 1);
                View mFocusedViewLike = mFocusedView.findViewById(this.mLikeResource.intValue());
                View mFocusedViewNope = mFocusedView.findViewById(this.mNopeResource.intValue());
                setAlpha(mFocusedViewLike, 0.0F, 0.0F);
                setAlpha(mFocusedViewNope, 0.0F, 0.0F);
                mFocusedView.scrollTo(0, 0);
            }

        }

        private void detectSwipe() {
            int imageHalf = this.mFocusedView.getWidth() / 2;
            this.mNeedToScrollX = this.mFocusedView.getWidth() - this.mTotalScrolledX;
            if(this.mScrollDirection == SwipeView.ScrollDirection.NONE) {
                if(this.mNeedToScrollX < imageHalf) {
                    this.mScrollDirection = SwipeView.ScrollDirection.OUT;
                } else {
                    this.mScrollDirection = SwipeView.ScrollDirection.IN;
                    setAlpha(this.mFocusedViewLike, 0.0F, 0.0F);
                    setAlpha(this.mFocusedViewNope, 0.0F, 0.0F);
                }
            }

            this.mScrollHandler.post(this.mScrollRunnable);
        }

        public void likeCard() {
            if(this.getChildCount() > 0) {
                this.mFocusedView = this.getChildAt(this.getChildCount() - 1);
                this.mFocusedViewLike = this.mFocusedView.findViewById(this.mLikeResource.intValue());
                this.mFocusedViewNope = this.mFocusedView.findViewById(this.mNopeResource.intValue());
                if(this.mScrollDirection != SwipeView.ScrollDirection.NONE) {
                    return;
                }

                this.resetScrollingValues();
                this.mScrollDirection = SwipeView.ScrollDirection.OUT;
                this.mScrollModeX = SwipeView.ScrollMode.LEFT;
                this.mFocusedViewLike.setVisibility(0);
                setAlpha(this.mFocusedViewLike, 0.0F, 1.0F);
                this.detectSwipe();
            }

        }

        public void dislikeCard() {
            if(this.getChildCount() > 0) {
                this.mFocusedView = this.getChildAt(this.getChildCount() - 1);
                this.mFocusedViewLike = this.mFocusedView.findViewById(this.mLikeResource.intValue());
                this.mFocusedViewNope = this.mFocusedView.findViewById(this.mNopeResource.intValue());
                if(this.mScrollDirection != SwipeView.ScrollDirection.NONE) {
                    return;
                }

                this.resetScrollingValues();
                this.mScrollDirection = SwipeView.ScrollDirection.OUT;
                this.mScrollModeX = SwipeView.ScrollMode.RIGHT;
                this.mFocusedViewNope.setVisibility(0);
                setAlpha(this.mFocusedViewNope, 0.0F, 1.0F);
                this.detectSwipe();
            }

        }

        public void setTouchable(boolean touchable) {
            this.enableTouchSwipe = touchable;
        }

        public static void setAlpha(View view, float fromAlpha, float toAlpha) {
            if(VERSION.SDK_INT < 11) {
                AlphaAnimation alphaAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(fromAlpha, toAlpha);
                alphaAnimation.setDuration(0L);
                alphaAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
                view.startAnimation(alphaAnimation);
            } else {
                view.setAlpha(toAlpha);
            }

        }

        public interface OnCardSwipedListener {
            void onLikes();

            void onDisLikes();

            void onSingleTap();
        }

        private static enum ScrollDirection {
            IN,
            OUT,
            NONE;

            private ScrollDirection() {
            }
        }

        private static enum ScrollMode {
            LEFT,
            RIGHT,
            TOP,
            BOTTOM,
            NONE;

            private ScrollMode() {
            }
        }
    }
```

**ATTEMPT #3**
This is the code that i've tried but I keep getting the same result (read comment below what I have done:

```
FrameLayout view = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.contentLayout);
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
view.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bitmap = view.getDrawingCache();
```

Comment: Hello Karen, 
The image that i'm trying to display is the 'contentLayout'. Im putting the image inside the contentLayout in a new folder and i've added the for loop so the image that gets saved keeps getting a new name. pic + i (number that increments) + .png.

Comment: onLikes is used for 10 different images. If the image is being liked or swiped to the right, the image gets saved in my sd card under the name of pic- + i + .png

Therefor every image gets a different name and i'm able to save more than 1 image. (I've also tried this with timestamps and it works fine).

I'll show more code but everything works pretty good except when I press like the Image that is GOING to appear gets saved instead of the image that is actually in the View (which I want to save)

Comment: Thanks for your patience and sorry for my misunderstanding of your code. I understand now and have removed my longwinded irrelevant comment! Thanks for posting more code, it helped me determine the problem. Take a look at my answer below and let me know if it helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the image you are trying to save is getting removed during the onSwipe due to the library code. I think you need to move your code to *before* the onLike is called.

You're also attempting to get a bitmap from the cache of the entire layout, rather than the wanted ImageView here:

```
bm=contentLayout.getDrawingCache();
```

You'll want to get your current *card view* as a View, then, from my understanding of your code, the ID of your *actual ImageView containing the expected bitmap* is R.id.imgMeals, so I the suggest replacing the line:

```
bm=contentLayout.getDrawingCache();
```

with the following:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) cardView.findViewById(R.id.imgMeals); 
BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
Bitmap bm = drawable.getBitmap();
```

Move *all* of the below code from where you have it, to where I have marked **//HERE!!** in the following part of your code (or better, move it to a new method and call the method here).

```
// If the imageview of like is clicked
case R.id.imgLike: {
    // HERE!!

    // The imageview in the contentlayout will be swiped to the right
    mSwipeView.likeCard();
    break;
}
```

This is the code to me moved including the change I mention above:

```
    View cardView = mSwipeView.getChildAt(mSwipeView.getChildCount() - 1);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) cardView.findViewById(R.id.imgMeals); 
    BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
    Bitmap bm = drawable.getBitmap();

    OutputStream fOut = null;
    try {
        // Save on my sd card
        File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                // Making a folder name Food Inspiration
                + File.separator + "Food Inspiration" + File.separator);
        root.mkdirs();
        File sdImageMainDirectory = null;

        // Loop for having a different name for every image
        int i = 0;
        do {
            sdImageMainDirectory = new File(root, "pic-" + i + ".png");
            i++;
        } while (sdImageMainDirectory.exists());
        fOut = new FileOutputStream(sdImageMainDirectory);

        // Updates the gallery of your phone with the folder and the "liked" images in it
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[] { sdImageMainDirectory.getAbsolutePath() }, null, null);

        // If something goes wrong
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error occured. Please try again later.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    // Compresses the actual bitmap image
    try {
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
    } catch (Exception e){}
```

Comment: I've tried implementing your code. But the cardview in :
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) cardView.findViewById(R.id.imgMeals); 
appears red. Is this because its never initialized? if so how should I initialize this ?

Comment: Alright, 
Yes indeed im using a library. I've updated my post with the library.
Search for the onLikes or addCard and you can see how it works. 
If you have any questions i'll reply as fast as possible :)

Comment: Alright understood!
I'll do my best! Thanks for your time and effort :)
I'll come back with what I have tried and maybe you can tell me if i'm heading in the right direction or not.

Comment: I've done some research and I hope this makes sense but 
I want to save Images inside a FrameLayout. I initialized the framelayout, I made it possible to have a temporary memory where I can save the framelayout after i've converted the framelayout into a bitmap. However I still keep having the Image saved that comes after the image that is currently shown. Isn't is possible to have something like a -1 working for simply bypassing the problem? (I've updated my post with my attempt)

Comment: For some reason im not able to adjust the SwipeView class any idea why?

Comment: Hello Karen,

I think i've stumbled across something that might be interesting.
My meals list has 10 images, i've logged them and found out they start at 0,1,2 till 9. 
But the SwipeView.class often says > 0 so it never gets the first picture.
For example: 
public void likeCard() {
        if(this.getChildCount() > 0)  

Could you check if this is the error that is causing my first image to be skipped when being liked.

Comment: Nevermind i see this line now:
this.mFocusedView = this.getChildAt(this.getChildCount() - 1);

the -1 nullifies the > 0

Comment: Hey karen, kind of you to ask! Im still trying.. but without succes. I just cant wrap my head around it. Tell me what you think about this: after the swipe or like the image that is in the contentlayout gets saved. So not during the like. It seems that my program doesnt seem to recognize the current image on top or just starts saving the image after i click like instead of during the click. Does this seem correct to you?

Comment: Wow i actually thought about trying that! I'll try as soon as i get home and respond asap.

Comment: Hey karen im back,

I've tried implementing the syntax, but with -2 i keep saving the image that is 2 spots behind the actual viewable image and -1 keeps saving the image after the image that I actually want to save. 
I've tried adjusting the numbers but it keeps crashing:
my code that i've tried;
        View cardView = mSwipeView.getChildAt(mSwipeView.getChildCount() - 2);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) cardView.findViewById(R.id.imgMeals);
        BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable)
                imageView.getDrawable(); Bitmap bm = drawable.getBitmap();

Comment: Yeah I can definitely see the image that I want to save and I understand about the -2 and -1 but having no minus makes it crash

Comment: Wauw, im now able to add the correct picture when I press the like button! But it doesnt work when I try to swipe it. Is this because the swipefunction is never called  in case.R.id.imgLike?

Comment: Glad to hear it worked! Did you leave the call to   mSwipeView.likeCard(); under where you moved the code to? You'll still need that line but underneath all the code for saving the image

Comment: Alright i'll continue trying. 
I'll delete my latests comments here. Thnx for helping and your time

Comment: I think let's delete all the comments from under the answer and I can edit my answer up a bit to make it readable for someone who stumbles upon the question. I'll delete my comments too. And no problem.

Comment: You should probably put the old code back in the question so the answer makes sense too. I'm actually intrigued to know if you put those old lines about the bitmap cache in saveCard rather than the new lines I gave you for getting the cardView, it might also work. I've never worked with drawing cache before. Might be worth trying :)

Comment: I've put them back in my code and it gives the same result, except it give me exactly a picture of my contentLayout with the image inside it. 
I've also noticed that it's slower compared to your method. 
Apparently the onLikes contains both the swipe function and the click function. (they both save the image behind my top image)
I'm going to stick to your method because this saves only the image and not the layout. 
Is it possible in someway to get the ID of image or the layout and then using a -1 to save it? Or is this a bad way to bypass my problem(if possible to bypass)

Comment: Study setting tags on Views in Android and you could set them to the image view of your card view. Again, this is a new problem and you're not spending time researching online or you should be able to work through it, if you can't work it out you should ask a new question.